# Help with MySQL query clause in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need some help solving a problem with mySQL, is it possible to pass an array to a function and then run a match agains the array values?

I have this query

```
function getMenu($cookieId) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('categoryTable');
    $this->db->join('userMenuTable', 'categoryTable.categoryId = userMenuTable.categoryId', 'left');
    $this->db->where('userMenuTable.cookieId', $cookieId);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();

}
```

Using the `$query` array that is returned is possible to query the database and get all the values from a table that do not match the array values?

Comment: Can you post the contents of `$query`? I have not used CI myself, but understanding how the array is returned would help in answering how you can call the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this condition in your query:

```
$this->db->where_not_in('fieldname', $array_of_values);
```

You won't be able to directly use the array returned in your example, as it comes from a `SELECT *` and thus it contains all fields of the table. You have to build an array with ONLY the values of the field you want to filter you next query on.

Answer (score 0):

What columns do you have in that array ?
Theoretically you could do a

```
select from `new table` where `field` NOT IN (Select `field` from `old_table`)
```

to do this in just one query, or pass your array the NOT IN condition